# using resource bitmap

Tags: vb.net, my.resources

I cannot figure this out: I added a resource "kurzor_10.png" and I'm trying to use it like this:

```
Dim bm As Bitmap = New Bitmap(My.Resources.kurzor_10)
```

This doesn't work. MS Studio offers me in the above code under My.Resources.{selection}  **ALL other PNG files**, but not this one! And they work perfectly.
They all have "Build action" set to "None", though I tried also "Embeded resource".
All the other PNG files are 16x16, the one I want to use is 10x10.

Any ideas, what I am doing wrong?

Regards,

Libor

Comment: I guess no one knows the answer... I used a workaround and stored the PNG files on the server, where each instance is taking the icon :-(